# How to render dynamic the quantity of svg shape element in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, svg

My svg shape elements and they attributes was query from server side then
how to render that dynamically in vue to use v-for without static html tag?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the response from the server. It's hard to advise without knowing the structure of your data.

Comment: My response from the server is like this array
[
  { type:'rect',attr:'arrtString''},
  { type:'circle',attr:'arrtString''},
  ...
]
How can I render that data using v-for or some Iteration in vue ?

Comment: To give you most helpful answer could you also show me what the arrtString looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a [Render Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). For example:

Create `SvgElement.vue`:

```
render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(
        this.shapeType,
        {
            attrs: this.attrObj
        },
        this.$slots.default
    )
},
props: {
    shapeType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    attrString: {
        type: string
    }
},
computed: {
    attrObj() {
        // Convert this.attrString into an object
        // eg return { cx: 50, cy: 50, r: 10, fill: 'red' }
    }
}
```

Then use in `MyComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <svg width="400" height="400">
        <SvgElement
            v-for="svg in svgArray"
            :key="svg.key"
            :shapeType="svg.type"
             :attrString="svg.attr"
        />
    </svg>
</template>

<script>
import SvgElement from './SvgElement'
export default {
    components: {
        SvgElement
    },
    data () {
        return {
            svgArray: [
                { type: 'rect', attr: 'attrString', key: 'shape1' },
                { type: 'circle', attr: 'attrString', key: 'shape2' }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It seem work, Thank you so much but I got this warn in my console
Property or method "key" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

What's going on here ? It is like the key problem but It does seem declare already ?

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html. Its recommenced to have a unique identifier for each element when using a for loop, so in my answer I suggested adding a key property which would need to be returned by the server. If there's something else thats unique across elements then you could just use that. For instance, maybe the type + attrs are unique so you could use :key="svg.type + sag.attr". You could get rid of the key attribute all together but you will receive a warning in the console.

Comment: All right! I have unique Rd come from server then I had bind it  I try to echo the value of key in my click handle function($event,key) { consle.log(key)} but the result of console.log was an index, How can I get this key in event handle?